# Flex SDK looks OK in Libraries, gives "Not Found"error when building

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex

I'm trying to build a Flex project in Eclipse on a client's machine, I didn't set it up. When I look in the project's "Flex Build Path" it shows the proper Flex SDK, expanding it shows the normal list of swc's with no errors reported. In project's "Flex Compiler", the same version is selected as what is in the library path list. In Preferences/Flex/Installed Flex SDKs, the same Flex version is listed there without any errors. For a sanity check, I set the path to somewhere that the SDK was not, and it does give an error.

When I try to build the project, it gives the error:

> Flex SDK location "/path/to/existing/SDK" does not exist

Any ideas on what I need to check / adjust / reinstall? I've never seen this before, normally you set the path to be correct in preferences, and the compilation is happy.

Comment: By which way are you initiating the build process?  Check Run As => Run Configurations and see if all the dependencies are correctly set up in the one you are running.  If nothing helps, try replacing the old configuration with a brand new one.

Comment: @weltraumpirat I'm getting the same results with either control-B or the menu Project/Build. I'll check the run-as configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling the Flex SDK, and that corrected the issue.

Everything appeared to be fine with the SDK, project, and run-as setup, I compared it setting-for-setting and file-for-file with my computer (which worked fine, but isn't on the client's network, so no access to the web services), and everything was identical. After the SDK re-install, everything appears fine.

So, I still have no idea what was in the weeds, which is annoying.